# Getting UTM coordinates of Blender GIS

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, export, vertices, normal-map

I created a terrain following an actual area (5 km X 3 km) using Blender GIS. My steps: Blender GIS > Base map > Get Elevation > Get OSM. Then I exported it into a .STL file, as I want to use it later in OpenFOAM.

However, I want to know the UTM coordinates of the 4 vertices of my initial terrain created using Blender GIS. Currently, I can only see very general XYZ coordinates specified for the blender file and not related to a global coordinate system.

Can some scholar explain to me how can I get UTM (or any global coordinate) coordinates of the vertices of my blender file?

Thank you in advance.